# Drag formulas across rows based on the date

Tags: excel, vba, date, range

I wrote a piece of code that fills a range of cells with a formula that should stop at a specific month column. The macro will automatically find the column corresponding to the current month and stop filling the formula at that column.

Currently, I have it so it searches row 4, which is the row with my dates. However, I'd like it to be a bit more dynamic and look for the letter "D" at the beginning of the row to signify that it's the date row.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks!!

Here's the original code:

```
Sub DragFormulaToMonth()

Dim mdate As Date

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = "m" Or Cells(i, 1) = "M" Then
        mdate = Worksheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
        mcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(mdate), Range("4:4"), 0)
        Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, mcol)).FillRight
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Here's what I've tried to make the date row specification more dynamic:

Here's what I've tried to make it more dynamic:

```
Sub DragFormulaToMonth()

Dim mdate As Date

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(i, 1) = "m" Or Cells(i, 1) = "M" Then
        mdate = Worksheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
        If Cells(i, 1) = "D" Then
            mcol = Application.Match(mdate, Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, Columns.Count)), 0)
            If Not IsError(mcol) Then
                Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, mcol)).FillRight
            End If
        End If
        Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, mcol)).FillRight
     End If
 Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual value in the first cell of the Date row?

Comment: Also, `If Cells(i, 1) = "D"` can never return true -- I hope the edited code (with proper indentation) makes itclear why

Comment: Hey @cybernetic.nomad thanks for the reply! The first cell in the date row is D... the dates between at cell G5 and continue to DD5.. Why can't it return true? Ugh, I'm wracking my brain

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `Debug.print Cells(i, 1)` or a `print Cells(i, 1)` in the `immediate window` you'll notice you get a blank as a result

What you actually want is `Cells(i, 1).Value` to return the actual cell content so you'll need to modify your `If` statements to `Cells(i, 1).Value`

Also instead of having two separate `If` statements for "M" and "m", you can use `If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "M" Then`

Answer (score 0):

The code first checks to see if `Cells(i, 1) = "m" Or Cells(i, 1) = "M"` then, if it is, it looks to see `If Cells(i, 1) = "D" Then`. Clearly, if `Cells(i,1)` is `M`, it cannot be `D`

Maybe this will do what you want?

```
Sub DragFormulaToMonth()

Dim mdate As Date

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(i, 1).Value  = "m" Or Cells(i, 1) = "M" Then
        mdate = Worksheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
    End if
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "D" Then
        mcol = Application.Match(mdate, Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, Columns.Count)), 0)
        If Not IsError(mcol) Then
            Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, mcol)).FillRight
        End If
    End If
    Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, mcol)).FillRight
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your amazing feedback. I was able to use your recommendations to solve me problem. Here's the final code that worked for me:

```
Sub StoreRowWithD()
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim firstDRow As Long

' Get the last row in Column 1
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row in Column 1 until we find a row with "D"
For rowNum = 1 To lastRow
    If Left(Cells(rowNum, 1), 1) = "D" Then
        ' If the first character of the cell in Column 1 of this row is "D",
        ' store the row number and exit the loop
        firstDRow = rowNum
        Exit For
    End If
Next rowNum

Dim mdate As Date
Dim mcol As Long

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "M" Then
        mdate = Worksheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
        mcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(mdate), Cells(firstDRow, 1).EntireRow, 0)
        Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, mcol)).FillRight
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub